# Not able to change the virtual emulator ram size in android studio

Tags: android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I have downloaded android studio . And build a helloexample app and want to run it. But i am facing some problem . My computer has 2gb ram . I have set the HAXM ram size to 512mb and I change the emulator phone ram to be 128mb that is the minimum . But when I run the emulator it show this error.

```
emulator: WARNING: Increasing RAM size to 1GB
emulator: device fd:776
HAXM is not working and emulator runs in emulation mode
emulator: The memory needed by this AVD exceeds the max specified in your HAXM configuration.
emulator: AVD      RAM size = 1024 MB
emulator: HAXM max RAM size = 512 MB
emulator: You might want to adjust your AVD RAM size and/or HAXM configuration to run in fast virt mode.
creating window 47 95 393 653
emulator: emulator window was out of view and was recentered
emulator: UpdateChecker: skipped version check
```

I have set the AVD ram size to 1024 Mb But when I check the emulator edit screen it is showing only 128mb. The emulator is starting but getting stuck on the Android boot screen.
I think that that ram is the problem that why emulator is not running properly.

I appreciate any answer.
Please help

Comment: I suggest to take a look at Genymotion, which is a better alternative to the default emulator.

Comment: Can you can tell me how to download and install . I have tried but not able to do that

Comment: you have multiple tutorials online with a simple Google search, for instance, http://www.coderefer.com/how-to-install-genymotion/